# Python Typing Hints

Tags: python, python-typing

I would like to know if there's a way of not implementing two Vector aliases (Vector1 and Vector2), and reusing a single Vector hint.

```
from typing import Union, TypeVar, Generic, List, Set, Tuple, FrozenSet

Number = Union[int, float]
Vector1 = Union[List[Number], Set[Number], Tuple[Number], FrozenSet[Number]]
Vector2 = Union[List[str], Set[str], Tuple[str], FrozenSet[str]]

def mean(vector: Vector1) -> Number:
    return (sum(vector) / len(vector))

def readPrint(vector: Vector2) -> None:
    for i in vector: print(i)
```

Comment: Your functions would throw an error, have you tried it?

Comment: You ask about implementation, but your title talks about type hints.

Comment: Could you just please elaborate on what is the purpose of this implementation? python is dynamically typed, you can set you class vector with any of tuple and list, and mean and readPrint would still work.

Comment: Error? Ah! I didn't put the imports. I will change it.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking about? The implementation? The annotations? Something else? Your class does not implement an iterator, so both ``sum(vector)`` and ``for i in vector:`` would not be correct. In that regard, the answer is just "no".

Comment: @GuintherKovalski I am just practicing, it's not a serious implementation. The whole purpose is to give a hint about the types I am looking forward to work with which are list, set, tuple, and frozenset. I would like be more specific, and say the type of the items inside list, set, tuple, or frozenset. For not creating two aliases, I tried to make a generic class, and use it, nevertheless I don't know if this is good practice.

Comment: The functions aren't inside of the class... If they were, it would throw indeed an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a generic type that is not a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363364/how-to-define-a-generic-type-that-is-not-a-class)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yeah! It does ^^! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work because your `Vector` class doesn't implement the `Iterable` or `Sized` protocols.  You *could* fix it to do that (and pass through to the `_store`), but with the code you've given it would be simpler to represent the typing you desire for `mean` and `readPrint` by just aliasing `Vector` to `Collection`:

```
from typing import Collection


Vector = Collection


def mean(vector: Vector[float]) -> float:
    return sum(vector) / len(vector)


def readPrint(vector: Vector[str]) -> None:
    for i in vector:
        print(i)


print(mean({2, 3, 4}))
readPrint(["foo", "bar"])

mean(["foo", "bar"])  # error: List item has incompatible type "str"; expected "float"
```

Note that `int` already conforms to `float` so defining a union of the two is typically not necessary in order to denote a numeric value.